# MATLAB SYNTAX - obtain [pxx ,f] vectors from periodogram(_ fs); <-- Errors in user's current usage

Tags: matlab, vector, syntax, window, figure

**QUESTION: How do I correctly use [pxx, f] = periodogram(y_soundsource_data,window,nfft, Fs);?**

**For context ...** trying to get the PSD local maxima, for 3 specific frequency ranges. I want both the x-frequency values and the PSD-y values.

(This was my trial yesterday which was very wrong --->  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56468/normalizing-vectors-to-be-the-same-size-to-retain-psd-data)

I sent an email to someone, and he said to use the [pxx, f]= periodogram(_ Fs) version of the periodogram call.

Where pxx= the PSD y value vector
and f= the x values which correspond to the frequency values that match 1:1 to the pxx points

**Matlab Documentation Says:**
[image]

**Undesired Behavior:**

- When I do use [pxx, f] = periodogram(y_soundsource_data,window, nfft,
  Fs); a window maker pops up and it doesn't automatically plot or
  calculate anything.
- Tried function call--> [pxx, f]=periodogram([],Fs); which should give
  the PSD-estimate with default values, but then, it caused an error. 
  [image: error image]

**Code**

```
    %% audioread .wav file
[y Fs]= audioread('100-daddy1.wav');
%% y=source signal
sourceFig=figure(1);
plot(y);
xlabel('milliseconds'); ylabel('amplitude'); title('spectrogram = voice source signal');

%% PSD - Power Spectral Density <-- peaks here should give formants
filterfcn=figure(2);
PSD=periodogram(y); %calculate the power spectral density of the source signal
plot(PSD);
ylabel('magnitude || intensity of signal'); xlabel('frequency in Hz'); title('PSD of Source');
xlim([0, .35*10^4]);

%% [pxx,f] = periodogram(_,fs)
%fs is the fourth input to periodogram 
% to use default values, do [], for preceding args
[pxx4, f]= periodogram( [], Fs);
disp(sizeof(pxx4));
disp(sizeof(f));
```

**How do I correctly use [pxx, f] = periodogram(y_soundsource_data,window,nfft, Fs);**

I need the pxx and f vectors to be able to index to find maxima.

Answer (score 0):

The reason window plotter came up, was because you used the window gate way function as an input argument to the call: **[pxx, f] = periodogram(y_soundsource_data,window, nfft, Fs).**

Deconstructing the **[pxx, f]= periodogram(y_soundsource_data, window, nfft, Fs);**

1. You can get y_soundsource_data and Fs<-- sampling frequency, from the audioread function. `file[y Fs]= audioread('100-daddy1.wav');`
2. window and nfft are not understood by the periodogram function UNLESS you define them.

   - **y_soundsource_data** and **Fs** are understood, because audioread returns the data metrics.
   - **nfft** - refers to the number of points used in the DFT. A larger nfft value will lead to a better estimation. nfft MUST be an integer. You can't have half a point.
   - **window** = vector of the size of the y_soundsource_data. 1:length_y_soundsource_data
   - both **window** and **nfft** need to be defined before you call the periodogram function.

Comment: the documentation. Read slowly and calmly. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html